# Critical and saddle points for the function f(x,y)=x^2y

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

I am not sure how to find the critical points and saddle points of the function as when I did the second partial derivative test for the function, it gave me $-4x^2$ which is always negative except when $x=0$, however according to wolfram alpha and there are 0 saddle points for the function. May someone explain where I went wrong? I would also like help in calculating local max and mix for the function. Thanks in advance! I am a bit new to mathstackexchange and my formatting is a bit off, sorry.

My work:

1. $f_x= 2xy, f_y= x^2$
2. $f_{xx}= 2y, f_{yy}= 0$
3. $f_{xy}=2x$

By the second partial derivative test, I get $0x^2-(2x)^2$ which simplifies to $-4x^2$, which would mean that for any x value other than 0, the determinant of Hessian matrix is negative which would mean that the point is a saddle point, however, looking at the graph of the function $f(x,y)=x^2y$, there are 0 saddle points. Sorry for the bad formatting and thanks in advance!

Comment: The critical points are the points where the first partial derivatives are zero. As $f_y = x^2$, that can only occur when $x=0$.

Comment: I understand that the critical points of the function are found when the gradient is equal to the 0 vector however, I don't understand why the 2nd partial derivative test is telling me every point other than when x=0 is a sadle point when its not. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to calculate Hessian at critical points. If $x = 0$ then Hessian is $0$ implying that second derivative test is failed.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot when the Hessian is equal to 0, that the test fails thanks!

Comment: Optimization Problem with f(x,y)=x^2y and x^2+4xy=1400
I understand that you can solve this problem by just writing x in terms of y or vice versa and then solving for the local max and min, however is it possible to solve this problem using multivariable calculus by using the partial derivatives and other tools, if so can someone please show me. Thanks in advance!

The question itself:

What are the dimensions of a squared based box without a top side/cover will maximize the volume of the box if the total surface area of the box without the topside is 1400.

Comment: You can use [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) method for solving constrained maxima or minima.

Comment: The stationary points are $x = 0$. If $y_0 < 0$, then $x^2 y \leq 0$ in a small neighborhood of $(0, y_0)$. So $f$ has local maximums at $x = 0 \land y < 0$ and local minimums at $x = 0 \land y > 0$. $(0, 0)$ is a saddle point because $f$ changes sign in any neighborhood of $(0, 0)$. The optimization problem should probably be a separate question.